# Popover on SVG-Path Element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am looking for a way to create a Popover on a SVG-Path Element.

Im making an angular 1 app showing clickable car parts.

To be clear the popover has to be right on top of the specific part.
Preferably right where the cursor is.

I found these options to make Popovers in general in an angular content:

http://github.hubspot.com/drop/docs/welcome/  - see Popover

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover -Popover

But these do not full fill my positioning needs or the option to be applied to Paths.

[image: This is how its supposed to look in a mock]

Thanks already

Comment: You might want to add CSS to your tags

Comment: Create a <title> child on the path element for a native popup. It's off-topic to ask for libraries here. If you feel there's something wrong with the code you already have, we would need to see it in order to suggest how it might be improved.

Comment: Is it possible to put buttons or other interactive elements into the title? I already tried butting in some things but i couldnt make it clickable. @RobertLongson

Comment: Not with a native title, you'd need to code something yourself so it is doable.

Comment: Use <title>, Dont use <title>, code something yourself... Bother giving me a hint? @RobertLongson

Comment: Create whatever you want and change its visibility on hover. Mind writing an attempt at a solution and explaining where you're stuck?